# How can I know which imperial units my dimensions are in Blender?

Tags: transforms, units, dimensions

I watched a tutorial in which the tutor put 10ft saying the Blender would convert it automatically, the Imperial units were initially in meters. But I wasn't able to to that, the command is not accepted if I put any letters in front of my figures like `10FT`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 3.4.1 you can write `10ft` (with or without space, capse or not) in location and dimensions inputs, ant it will result in `3.048 m`.

If it doesn't work, check your Blender version. I think this was implemented back in 2.80

Comment: I hope it results in 3.048 m, otherwise my trust in Blender's unit conversion would be seriously damaged  ;-)

Comment: oops  thanks for the catch